# Do I need to close a Cursor if moveToFirst() is false?

Tags: android, android-cursor

If `cursor.moveToFirst()` returns false do I still need to close it?
Since it returns false when the cursor is empty.

I'm doubt about the correct approach:

```
if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    // some code
    cursor.close();
}
```

Or:

```
if(cursor != null) {
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        // some code
    }

    cursor.close();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must close all `Cursors` which are not nulls, regardless of whether they have populated entries or not.

The only exception to the above statement would be if you know that the `Cursor` in question is managed by some "external" framework and will be automatically closed without your interaction (as is the case with `LoaderManager` framework when used with `CursorLoader`).

At least two (good) reasons to close any non-null `Cursor`:

1. Empty `Cursors` can have "memory-allocations" which need to be explicitly released even if they are empty (as is the case with `AbstractWindowedCursor`)
2. Empty `Cursor` can become non-empty if `requery()` is called. Your means to prevent this explicitly is to close the `Cursor`

The most general and error prone approach would be (it is an overkill in some cases):

```
Cursor c;
try {
    // Assign a cursor to "c" and use it as you wish
} finally {
    if (c != null) c.close();
}
```

Another popular pattern if you need to iterate over `Cursor's` entries:

```
if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
        // Do s.t. with the data at current cursor's position
    } while (c.moveToNext());
}
if (c != null) c.close();
```

Don't feel bad with one extra `c != null` comparison - it is totally justified in these cases.

Answer (score 0):

Closing an "empty" cursor doesn't hurt your app, call it anyway.

Theoretically, won't be any side effeects if you don't close it, but close it anyway, IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

From the official docs for `Cursor.moveToFirst()`:

```
Move the cursor to the first row.

This method will return false if the cursor is empty.
```

It said that it will return false if the `Cursor` is *empty*, not null. How could Android know whether or not a cursor's empty? Exactly, it will open said cursor.

So yes, You'd still need to close it.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (myCursor.moveToFirst()) {
    do {

          // work .....

    } while (myCursor.moveToNext());
}
```

or  simply...

```
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
    // use cursor
}
```